# Labelling a Map

Tags: python, labeling, shapely, matplotlib, cartopy

I have a map I have made using python, matplotlib, cartopy and shapely. It has a coast, county borders, lakes and rivers. I also shade in districts, in the form of polygons, on the map in order to present data on it. I export it as an svg file. My goal is to create a map that I can put on my wall which is 16.5 x 23.4 inches, 420 x 594 cm in dimension. I hope the the style of the map is similar to that of the Fullarton Atlas from 1872 when I am finished.

I'd like to place labels on the map. For example, the names of the counties, where such labels follow a curve in order to span the county. Like this:

[image]

I'd also like to add town labels ensuring that they don't overlap each other. I have all the coordinates for the towns I wish to apply.

[image]

Are there any tools that I could use to place these labels on the map? It doesn't have to be in python and can be applied to the svg image. I am able to apply labels to the map using python and then adjust their position in Inkscape but this is a very manual process, and should the number of labels change or the dimensions of the map change I would need to start again from scratch. I'd like to be able to adjust things in Inkscape to some degree but I would still like to have a tool that does most of the work.

Comment: QGIS has many options of automatic label placement, did you have a look at it? Ideal label placement is always dependent on scale, so I'm not sure that you can preserve a solution when changing the scale. For high end (print) map output, I think you still will use a manual check. You could also do this in QGIS.

Comment: @Babel I've never used QGIS. I'm downloading now and will take a look. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe worth looking out for a few tutorials of label placement with QGIS as this is a very powerful software with a lot of options

Comment: See e.g. QGIS Training manual: 3.2. Lesson: Labels https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/training_manual/vector_classification/label_tool.html or the very helpful video tutorials by Klas Karlsson: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Qof4oDLxcmE or https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=ySYmZv7HQiY or https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=PWr85Oe0Yg0

Answer (score 0):

To make a text label follow a curve you could use the [CurvedText class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44521963). In the example below, I placed that class in the library "curved_text":

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import numpy as np
# this library has the CurvedText class from https://stackoverflow.com/a/44521963
import curved_text
from matplotlib.transforms import offset_copy

projection=ccrs.PlateCarree()

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=projection)

#define displayed area in degrees
map_left_lon = -10.6
map_bottom_lat = 50.9
map_width = 5.2
map_height = 5.2

# limit the extent of the map to a small longitude/latitude range
extent = [map_left_lon,
          map_left_lon + map_width,
          map_bottom_lat,
          map_bottom_lat + map_height]

ax.set_extent(extent, crs=ccrs.Geodetic())
# add land and ocean 
ax.add_feature(cfeature.LAND, zorder=0, edgecolor='black')
ax.add_feature(cfeature.OCEAN, zorder=0)

# make parametric curve for the curved text
N = 100
arch_start = np.deg2rad(22)
arch_end = np.deg2rad(76)
radius = 3.5
curve_x = map_left_lon + map_width - radius * np.cos(np.linspace(arch_start, arch_end, N))
curve_y = map_bottom_lat + radius * np.sin(np.linspace(arch_start, arch_end, N))

# place country name as curved text
text = curved_text.CurvedText(
                              x = curve_x,
                              y = curve_y,
                              text = 'I   R   E   L   A   N   D',
                              va = 'bottom',
                              axes = ax,
                              fontsize = 22,
                              color = 'green',
                              transform = ccrs.Geodetic()
)

# place Irish towns as normal text, with manually tuned alignments and offsets
irish_towns = {
    'Belfast': {'lon': -5.93, 'lat': 54.596389, 'x_off': -2, 'y_off': 2, 'v_al': 'bottom', 'h_al': 'right'},
    'Derry': {'lon': -7.32, 'lat': 54.9975, 'x_off': 2, 'y_off': -5, 'v_al': 'top', 'h_al': 'left'},
    'Dublin': {'lon': -6.260278, 'lat': 53.35, 'x_off': -2, 'y_off': -3, 'v_al': 'top', 'h_al': 'right'},
    'Cork': {'lon': -8.47, 'lat': 51.897222, 'x_off': -2, 'y_off': -3, 'v_al': 'top', 'h_al': 'right'},
    'Limerick': {'lon': -8.6238, 'lat': 52.6653, 'x_off': 2, 'y_off': -3, 'v_al': 'top', 'h_al': 'left'},
    'Galway': {'lon': -9.048889, 'lat': 53.271944, 'x_off': 0, 'y_off': 3, 'v_al': 'bottom', 'h_al': 'left'}
}
geodetic_transform = ccrs.Geodetic()._as_mpl_transform(ax)
for name, data in irish_towns.items():
    text_transform = offset_copy(geodetic_transform, units='dots', x=data['x_off'], y=data['y_off'])
    ax.plot(data['lon'], data['lat'], marker='o', markersize=5, color='green', markeredgecolor='black', alpha=0.8, transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
    ax.text(data['lon'], data['lat'], name,
            verticalalignment=data['v_al'],
            horizontalalignment=data['h_al'],
            transform=text_transform)

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The result:
[image]

To ensure that your labels do not overlap, you could use the [adjustText library](https://github.com/Phlya/adjustText):

```py
import pandas as pd
import geopandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
from adjustText import adjust_text

cm = 1/2.54  # centimeters in inches

projection=ccrs.PlateCarree()

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(40*cm, 70*cm))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=projection)

map_left_lon = 34.8
mape_right_lon = 35.6
map_bottom_lat = 31.2
map_top_lat = 32.6

extent = [map_left_lon,
          mape_right_lon,
          map_bottom_lat,
          map_top_lat]

# limit the extent of the map to a small longitude/latitude range
ax.set_extent(extent, crs=ccrs.Geodetic())
ax.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS)
ax.add_feature(cfeature.LAND)
ax.add_feature(cfeature.OCEAN)

# the file is downloaded from # https://data.humdata.org/dataset/state-of-palestine-settlements
fname = '.\\settlements_peacenow\\Settlements_Buildup_PeaceNow.shp'
all_gdf = geopandas.read_file(fname)
# transform to EPSG:4326
all_gdf.to_crs(epsg='4326', inplace=True)
# get centroids of polygons representing settlements
all_gdf['centroid'] = all_gdf.centroid
texts = []
# place markers and text labels with settlement names
for index, poi in all_gdf.iterrows():
    name = all_gdf.loc[index, 'Name']
    if name is not None:
        c = all_gdf.loc[index, 'centroid']
        lon = c.coords[0][0] # x
        lat = c.coords[0][1] # y
        ax.plot(lon, lat, marker='o', markersize=5, color='blue', alpha=0.7)
        t = ax.text(lon, lat, str(name))
        texts.append(t)
# rearrange text labels
adjust_text(texts, time_lim=30, arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='-', color='gray', alpha=.5), ax=ax)

# add country names
ax.text(34.85, 31.8, 'Israel', rotation=78, fontsize = 40)
ax.text(35.5, 31.4, 'Jordan', rotation=78, fontsize = 40)
ax.text(35.11, 32.35, 'West Bank', fontsize = 40)

plt.title('Israeli Settlements in the West Bank (Palestine)')
fig.tight_layout()
fig.savefig('Settlements.png')
plt.show()
```

The result shown in the matplotlib window looks terrible, but the properly sized picture saved in the file "Settlements.png" looks all right:
[image]

You may need to tune some arguments of `adjust_text()`, for example "time_lim" which is how much time you allocate for `adjust_text()` to do its job. Longer times seem to bring better results.